# Famous libraries for implementing 3d in javascript?

Tags: javascript, 3d

Which are the famouse 3d javascript libraries? By famous I mean something that is as famous Jquery is to web developers. By famous I mean things are properly documented and many resources are available i.e tutorials/books etc for newbies. I am trying to learn three.js but having hard time figuring out how to use because there isn't much documentation available for this. On top of that it is javascript so not even intellisense benefit ;) What are the other options for this type of 3d stuff? I am mainly interested in WebGL and Canvas.

Comment: WebGL is 3D, it is like OpenGL. Not a web dev. so I can't really tell you much more than that. But, if you weren't sure. WebGL is 3D.

Comment: @anon: I know WebGL is 3d. I have seen examples of three.js using WebGLRenderer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the great work of [Mr. Doob](http://mrdoob.com/) (i.e. [rome](http://www.ro.me/)), [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js) is quite famous.

Comment: I am looking at three.js only. It is the best one out there I think.

Answer (score 0):

If by famous you just mean 'popular', why not let google decide for you? When searching for [JavaScript 3D Library](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript%203d%20library), google seems to think the following is most popular.

http://www.c3dl.org/

It seems to fit your criteria, WebGL and Canvas.

Comment: E: I've already defined my meaning of "famous". The way Jquery is on the tip of tongue for every web developer that way this libary should be on the tip of tongue for every developer who is into 3d javascript.

Comment: I've googled and found many libraries. But the thing that doesn't show up on google is how many developers are currently using this library and so I asked this on SO before picking up a random library from google.

Comment: You are looking for something that does not exist. 3D is too much of a niche subject for there to be a 'famous' library